# R mtext/lines "plot.new has not been called yet" in markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a markdown for simple R functions for a course I am taking and to be able to reuse later. Only problem is when I copy my R code from various courses into the markdown, I get an error message.

**My original code**

```
A<-seq(1,10,1)
B<-rnorm(10,15,1.5)
C<-rnorm(10,25,1.5)

df<-cbind(A,B,C)

plot(A~B,df, type="l")
mtext("example",side=3, line=1)
```

**My Markdown chunk settings:**

```
{r, include=FALSE, echo=TRUE}
```

The plot itself is created just fine but running mtext gives following error:

```
Error in mtext("example", side = 3, line = 1) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

**adding a "+" to join plot() and mtext() has its own result:**

```
> plot(A~B,df, type="l") + mtext("example",side=3, line=1)
integer(0)
```

There has to be a simple solution, I don't want to use ggplot for everything XD, just quick plotting of basic functions/models to visualize what my data looks like... Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, the output is visible when the option show chunk output in the console is selected from the settings. Show Output Inline option is not working here. Also to get rid of the error you can select  and run the code inside the chunk.
[image]